# Could shear force from blending denature alpha amylase / glucoamylase enzymes?

Tags: food-chemistry, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

I am trying to break down the starches in a certain variety of oats in the most efficient way possible. I have to break the whole oats down after cooking, so they are finer particles for the amylases to do its work in the liquid.

I have been adding the amylases at the beginning of blending of the whole oats (at a temperature of about 35 centigrade) because I thought it would help the enzyme process, but could I be damaging / denaturing the enzyme from the shear forces of the blender (I am using a 600 Watt stick blender)

Answer (score 1):

Some proteins can be denatured mechanically, e.g. when whisking egg whites. This denaturing may or may not be reversible. I don't know how to estimate whether these exact enzymes under your conditions will denature or not and if so whether it will be reversible. You can add them after the blending step to be on the safe side.

Comment: thanks - I edited my question to explain why I initially thought to add the enzyme at the beginning of the blending stage

Comment: are there any kinds of denaturing which are reversible?

Comment: It really depends on how automatically the protein folds itself. But addition of salts (i.e. changing the ionic strength) may be reversible. The same might be true for changes in the pH. Sometimes denaturing (loss of function) occurs even with small changes to the natural environment of the enzyme. Those are likely to be reversible.